# How to cast to an array of objects?

Tags: swift, casting

In CourseViewController I have the following variable:

```
var courses =  [Course]()
```

declared at top

I try to segue to CourseViewController, by doing this

```
   let dc = segue.destination as! CourseListViewController
   dc.courses = items[tag] as! [Course]
```

Is that the right way to do so? "items[tag] as! [Course]" is this correct?

Comment: "is this correct?" Did you try running your code? Did your code work? If it did, your code is correct.

Comment: it doesn't work, that's why I'm asking

Comment: check whether the response is indeed an array of course.

Comment: @PotaOnasys did you work that out?

Comment: What is `items`?

Comment: It's not correct, if the type of `items[tag]` is [Course] then you don't need any cast at all and if it isn't you need to map from whatever the type of the elements in `items[tag]` are to `Course` using `map` (or `compactMap`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the item at that tag would surely be a `[Course]` then it's absolutely correct. If not, use an `if-let` or `guard` to avoid runtime exception

```
 if let courses = items[tag] as? [Course]{
    dc.courses = courses
 }
```